# Error 500 POST con Ionic y AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ionic, rest, login, cakephp

tengo un inconveniente al intentar realizar la autenticación con Ionic y AngularJs con un Backend en Cakephp 3. Probando con Postman de Chrome, todo funciona perfecto. El problema está al hacer la llamada con el controlador de Ionic. A continuación presento todos los elementos en cuestión:

```
// controllers.js
.controller('AuthCtrl', function($scope, $location, $stateParams, $ionicHistory, $http, $state, $auth, $rootScope) {

  $scope.loginData = {};
  $scope.loginError = false;
  $scope.loginErrorText;

  $scope.doLogin = function() {

    var credentials = {
      username: $scope.loginData.username,
      password: $scope.loginData.password
    }
    var header = {
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
      'Accept' : 'application/json'
    }

    $auth.login(credentials).then(function() {

      $http.post('http://fullday-backend/api/users/token', header).success(function(response) {

        var user = JSON.stringify(response.user);

        localStorage.setItem('user', user);

        $rootScope.currentUser = response.user;

        $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
          disableBack: true
        });

        $state.go('app.coupons');
      }).error(function() {
            $scope.loginError = true;
            $scope.loginErrorText = error.data.error;
            console.log($scope.loginErrorText);
            console.log("error");
      })
    });
  }
})
```

---

```
// App.js

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $authProvider) {

$authProvider.loginUrl = 'http://fullday-backend/api/users/token';

$stateProvider

.state('app.auth', {
  url: '/auth',
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
      controller: 'AuthCtrl'
    }
  }
})

.state('app', {
  url: '/app',
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
  controller: 'AppCtrl'
})

.state('app.search', {
  url: '/search',
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/search.html'
    }
  }
})

.state('app.browse', {
    url: '/browse',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/browse.html'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.coupons', {
    url: '/coupons',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/coupons.html',
        controller: 'couponsCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

.state('app.single', {
  url: '/coupons/:couponId',
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/coupon.html',
      controller: 'couponCtrl'
    }
  }
});
// if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/coupons');
});
```

PD: Importante destacar que al enviar datos incorrectos del usuario y la contraseña, rechaza la conexión con el código 401 de forma correcta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta llamar asi , `success` y `error` ya estan obsoletos

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://fullday-backend/api/users/token',
    dataType: "json",
    headers : {
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
      'Accept' : 'application/json'
    }

}).then(function(response) {

});
```

El error 500 es del lado del servidor, como dices que cuando envias los datos malos desde la app a tu servidor, recibes el error correcto (por ende descarto problema de CORS), el error que causa 500, debe estar pasando cuando envias los datos correctos.

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Solucionado el inconveniente colega! +1

Comment: @JeanManzo  saludos! Me alegro que se haya solucionado recuerda marcar como correcta la respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

> Estas usando mal [$http.post](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post)

```
$http.post(url, data, [config]);
```

- El primer parámetro se espera que sea la URL
- El segundo parámetro se espera que sea los datos a enviar
- El trcer parámetro se espera que sea la configuracion del AJAX

//

Con esta info, prueba hacerlo así:

```
$http.post('http://fullday-backend/api/users/token', null, {
  dataType: 'json'// Sirve para setear accepts y content-type
})
.then(function(response) {
  // Codigo aqui
});
```

Comment: El esta trabajando con angularjs, el $http.post esta bien, aunque obsoleto